# Understanding ros 2 navigation stack, white papers and software architecture sketches would help

Tags: navigation, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to understand the [ROS 2 navigation stack](https://github.com/ros2/navigation) and perhaps help in its development.

I am hoping if someone could suggest any white paper's/books on which it is based on. Also, Is there any documentation/sketches on the software architecture.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310686/understanding-ros-2-navigation-stack,-white-papers-and-software-architecture-sketches-would-help/) by [mann](https://answers.ros.org/users/38423/mann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2018-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I would like to understand the [ROS 2 navigation stack](https://github.com/ros2/navigation) and perhaps help in its development.

The repository that you link to is *not* the "ROS 2 navigation stack" if I understand everything correctly. It seems to be a (quick) port of the "ROS 1 navigation stack" to use ROS 2 infrastructure (it was used as a demo/test case for the state of ROS 2 quite a few months ago).

As such, the design is probably relatively similar to how it was in ROS 1.

The effort to implement a proper ROS 2 based navigation stack may be found at: [ros-planning/navigation2](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2).

The design documentation (and other documentation) for that may be found at: [ros-planning/navigation2/doc](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/tree/c55cc6eb8598bf83d2a64a838196b980ff4013a4/doc) (NOTE: I'm using a permalink here. If you're clicking this link in the future, make sure to read an up-to-date version of the documentation, not this old one).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mann](https://answers.ros.org/users/38423/mann/) on 2018-12-14**:
Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for